# Default value 0 to prevent suppression of sub-report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm fairly new to ssrs and I'm trying to creat a report with a sub-report which e.g. returns 3 fields / columns. 
When I export this to excel it reads

```
A1     B1    C1
100   50    100
```

When there's no data / dataset returns no records all cells A to C are merged to one cell?
Which makes processing the file a real pain...

I've tried the norowsmessage but then I get one value in the merged cells.
Can't remember I had this with Crystal Reports?

Is there something I can do to always return the sub-report with the 3 columns in it so my layout is retained?

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: Is there a reason for not including column headers in your report?

Comment: Hi Mark, headers are in the main report corresponding to the columns in the sub report

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it by using a Union statement in my SQL string:

```
SELECT        - SUM(QTY) AS EXPR1, - SUM(ENTEREDVALUE) AS EXPR2, - SUM(LINEAMOUNTMST) AS EXPR3
FROM            DBS_SUPERVISOR.STOCKTRANS
WHERE        (DATASET = 'CAT') AND (ITEMNUMBER = :myitem) AND (DATEPHYSICAL >= :VanDatum) AND     (DATEPHYSICAL <= :TotDatum) AND (STREFERENCE = 0) AND 
                     (DCTYPE = 1) AND (STATUSOUTFLOW = 1) AND (DCGROUP = 'GROUPX')
GROUP BY ITEMNUMBER
UNION ALL
SELECT        0 AS EXPR1, 0 AS EXPR2, 0 AS EXPR3
FROM            SYS."DUAL"
WHERE        (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        QTY AS EXPR1
                           FROM            DBS_SUPERVISOR.STOCKTRANS STOCKTRANS_1
                           WHERE        (DATASET = 'CAT') AND (ITEMNUMBER = :myitem) AND (DATEPHYSICAL >= :VanDatum) AND (DATEPHYSICAL <= :TotDatum) AND (STREFERENCE = 0) 
                                                     AND (DCTYPE = 1) AND (STATUSOUTFLOW = 1) AND (DCGROUP = 'GROUPX')))
```

This way if the top part doesn't return a row the bottom part will return 3 columns with 0

Regards,

Mike